# Log in and log out in asp.net pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, formsauthentication

I need to create a log in page in a asp.net web site. I declare this code in web.config file:

```
    <location path="Login.aspx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

```
<system.web><authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="MyAppCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Managment.aspx" ></forms>

</authentication>

<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>

</authorization><system.web>
```

And I have a button in Managment.aspx to exit which runs this code:

```
protected void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();
}
```

Every thing is OK, but when I try to log out using Exit button, I give this Error:

[image]
 But I have no Account Folder which specified in address bar! I have just a Login.aspx file in website root. I expected by clicking this button system transform control to Login.aspx Page directly. Is it right? How I can fix this problem?

Comment: try `<location path="~/Login.aspx">`

Comment: I try it it doesn't work!

Comment: Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your Login.aspx is in the root folder try using

```
loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"
```

The tilda notation will make the path relative to the website's root not the current page.

Answer (score 1):

If your login.aspx stays in root, just try

loginUrl="/Login.aspx"